# how to handle namespace version issue when using xsl namespace alias

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt file look like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:MM="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ManagementModel/Serialization/2011/09"
      xmlns:RE="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RelationalEngine/Serialization/2011/09"
      xmlns:dac="urn:dacFunctions"
      exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

The problem is that we might change the namespace from     `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ManagementModel/Serialization/2011/09 to     http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ManagementModel/Serialization/2011/10`

for new xmls, then the old xslt can not handle the new xml files without change the header.  I wonder whether we can have a smart way to allow one xlst to handle all version of namespace.

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963316/how-to-mention-namespace-in-xslt-file-when-the-namespaces-are-dynamic) if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that we might change the namespace from
>   `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ManagementModel/Serialization/2011/09`
>   to
>   `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ManagementModel/Serialization/2011/10`
>
> for new xmls, then the old xslt can not handle the new xml files
>   without change the header. I wonder whether we can have a smart way to
>   allow one xlst to handle all version of namespace.

There isn't a general way, but if there are certain limitations in place something is possible.

**Assuming that**:

1. All names that belong to the namespace `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ManagementModel/Serialization/2011/09"` are prefixed with `"mm:"`
2. The prefix `"mm:"` is used only in association with the same namespace.

**You can achieve namespace-uri independence in the following way**:

In any Xpath expression refer to a name (say `someName`) as:

```
*[starts-with(name(), 'mm:')]
```

and in the rare case when you might have attribute names in this namespace (not a recommended practice for attributes):

```
@*[starts-with(name(), 'mm:')]
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach to this is to preprocess the documents (typically, with another XSLT transformation) so they use a consistent namespace. The preprocessing stylesheet is extremely simple, and by doing it this way you avoid cluttering the main stylesheet with lots of complex conditional code. In addition the preprocessing code becomes completely reusable; you can use it in any pipeline.

If you need a bit more performance you could do the preprocessing in a SAX filter inserted between the XML parser and the transformer, where it would cost almost nothing.

(I also advise people to avoid packing version information into a namespace URI, but there's no telling Microsoft...)